# can you access the submitted data in an ajax call in the callbacks?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of select options that need ajax calls.  I was going to do something like:

```
$("select options").each(function(){
  var $id = $(this).val();
  var url = "www.sample.com/objects/"+$id;
  $.ajax([settings]);
});
```

On the sucess call, can i access the parameters passed into the ajax call? Example, i wanted to get the ID in the sucess call, and was thinking to either pass it into the ajax call somehow or just call split on the URL and obtain the last item from it.

I was looking through jquery and i wasnt sure if you can access the url or settings passed into the call in any of the callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
var $id = $(this).val();
var url = "www.sample.com/objects/"+$id;
var settings = {
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function( msg ) {
   console.log(settings);
   console.log($id);
   // You can access everything that was created inside your `.each` callback scope.
});
```

Comment: there is a kicker though.   they are global but in a loop, it is not guarenteed to be maintained.....   so it might change 3 times before the success is called.... which means wrong data.

Comment: that is why you have to be careful when creating variables in the global scope. I rarely do so, but when I do I do not use them in asynchronous operations.

Comment: inside the success you can call:   this.url and parse that for the $id.

Comment: it is best to clone global variables inside the scope you are working on and use the clone so it does not change

Comment: Normally, i pass cloned things into the data portion of an jquery object and then access it that way.

Comment: you can do that but be aware to not mess any jQuery object property already defined. use a custom namespace unique to your application or you may get weird problems hard to detect.